# PHP using regular expressions to extract content from a string

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I have the following String and I want to extract the "383-0408" from it, obviously the content changes but the part number always follows the String "Our Stk #:", how can I most elegantly extract this information from the string?

```
Microchip Technology Inc.
18 PIN, 7 KB FLASH, 256 RAM, 16 I/O 

Mfr's Part #: PIC16F648A-I/SO 
Our Stk #: 383-0408
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
<?php

$str = "Microchip Technology Inc.
18 PIN, 7 KB FLASH, 256 RAM, 16 I/O 

Mfr's Part #: PIC16F648A-I/SO 
Our Stk #: 383-0408";

if (preg_match('/Our Stk #: (\d*-\d*)/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

this works only if the number part you're looking for has always the form `digits-digits`. A more general solution, with any number and any amount of dashes is given by @Richard86 as another answer to your question.

**Edit:**

In order to avoid the case when no digits are around the dash, as @Richard86 said in a comment, the regular expresion should look like:

```
if (preg_match('/Our Stk #: (\d+-\d+)/', $str, $matches)) {
```

Comment: This solution is better to fit the form `digits-digits`, which is probably what @Timothy uses. Thanks for giving creds anyway. (If you want to exclude a Stk # with just a dash (e.g., `Our Stk #: -`), then `(\d*-\d*)` could be changed to `(\d+-\d+)`.)

Comment: @Richard86 You are completely right. Indeed I'll edit the answer to point that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'YOURSTRING';
$offset = strpos($string, 'Out Stk #') + 11;
$final = substr($string, $offset, 8);
```

if we do not know the length of the number then and lets say **whitespace** is next character after the number, then:

```
$string = 'YOURSTRING';
$offset = strpos($string, 'Out Stk #') + 11;
$end = strpos($string, ' ', $offset);
$final = substr($string, $offset, $end-$offset);
```

Comment: I have done it your way but I find the other answers to more suited to the question.

Comment: @Richard86 : we can find the length of it also, according to what is the next character after the number..probably just a white space

Comment: @Timothy I only wanted to inform future readers of it, even if it probably was obvious for most of us. Many times `substr()` is the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
if (preg_match( '/Our Stk #: ([0-9\\-]+)/', $str, $match ))
    echo $match[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$text = "Microchip Technology Inc.
18 PIN, 7 KB FLASH, 256 RAM, 16 I/O 

Mfr's Part #: PIC16F648A-I/SO 
Our Stk #: 383-0408";

preg_match('/Our Stk #: (.*)/', $text, $result);
$stk = $result[1];

?>
```